# Xdt transformation of inner values

Tags: xml, web-config, xdt-transform

I am trying to transform the following with an XML transformation file (xdt):

```
<serviceProperty name="Group">
  <expression>33</expression>
</serviceProperty>
```

Im looking to replace 33 with another number. I have figured out how to replace one occurance with

```
<expression xdt:Locator="XPath(//serviceProperty[@name='Group']/expression[text()='33'])" xdt:Transform="Replace" >48</expression>
```

But how would I make this work for all matching elements?

Answer (score 3):

You could try doing this in your .config file:

```
<serviceProperty name="Group">
    <expression xdt:Transform="Replace">45</expression>
</serviceProperty>
```